# Why this image is higher resolution then mine?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I am completely confused by why the header image for this webpage [here](http://syrup.design/ux-ui-redesign-case-study) is high resolution, yet when I create it in my HTML is comes out lower resolution. I am linking to the exact same img link. Although when I inspect the code this image has been linked by `img data-src`, could this affect the quality of the image?

If anybody knows anything around this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where’s your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image's address is:

> https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57c0dbb31b631b53bedecc7e/t/57c29deb6a4963efc2c2eced/1472372377741/uxuihero.jpeg

but if you look closely the actual `src` attribute of the `<image>` element is to

> https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57c0dbb31b631b53bedecc7e/t/57c29deb6a4963efc2c2eced/1472372377741/uxuihero.jpeg?format=2500w

Notice the `?format=2500w` at the end - it's a common practice for servers to to be asked to provide the image with a fixed width (this saves network traffic on mobile devices).

Once you add the query parameter to your own code you'll see the same image.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying to get this for hours!!

Answer (score 1):

The photo on this page has added background color with transparency. It works as photographic philtres.  It is that sample of code:

```
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
```